# How can I paste highlighted code that was copied from VS Code with the right indentation to Power Point?

Tags: visual-studio-code, powerpoint

I want to create a presentation with Power Point.
I need to copy dart codes with highlighting.
VS Code supports copying the codes with highlighting. 
But when I paste codes into Power Point, the indentation is removed.
How can I paste the codes with indentation?

Edit:
I think it is about the Mac version of the programs. I use VS Code and Power Point Mac versions.

[image]

Comment: if you are ok with images, you could use the [CodeSnap - VS Code Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=adpyke.codesnap)

Comment: sounds possibly related to [Issue with preserving code formatting when copying from Visual Studio Code to Google Docs](/q/76697894/11107541)

Answer (score 0):

###### PowerPoint: `Microsoft 365 - PowerPoint Version 2207`

###### VSCode: `Visual Studio Code 1.85`

###### OS: `Windows 11`

- This works just fine.
- Some text boxes that are already part of an existing presentation template may break the spacing
- If pasting from another computer, the clipboard may remove the formatting.
- If spacing is incorrect, instead of pasting to an existing text field, paste into an empty place in the document to create a new text field.
- Ensure VSCode and PowerPoint are both running on the same computer.

> [image: powerpoint]

Comment: Thank you.
I think it is about the Mac version of the programs.
I use VS Code and Power Point Mac versions.

Comment: @HasimYerlikaya I used a Windows 11 VM running on my Mac M1 for the above.   It's not ideal, but might save you a bunch of formatting:  Parallels (DEMO exists), Windows 11 (DEMO exists), Office 365 (DEMO exists).